# unable to register/sign-up in RealmTasks mobile app Demo via Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, realm, realm-mobile-platform

### Hello there, i have a problem logging in, the following is what i've done so far:

1. Installed ROS on a Ubuntu within a guest VM and set network settings to bridged so it'd be assigned a unique ip address 192.168.1.9 that is within the same LAN as my host machine.
2. I have already configured and registered my ROS and was able to login from the vm/guest browser as well as my host's web browser so i verified that it's capable of internet connectivity/requests.

   - HOWEVER after opening the RealmTasks project in Android Studio and running the app - (also i have an actual device LG 15332 connected instead of emulator) - I attempt to register with UN/PW and receive the following output

`06-06 10:43:06.331 12633-12771/io.realm.realmtasks D/REALM_JAVA: AuthenticateResponse - Error: UNKNOWN(-1) java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.9 (port 9080) after 10000ms at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:169) at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:886) at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.java:61) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:187) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.buildConnection(RealConnection.java:173) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:114) at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:193) at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:129) at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:98) at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:109) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:124) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:170) at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:60) at io.realm.internal.network.OkHttpAuthenticationServer.authenticate(OkHttpAuthenticationServer.java:111) at io.realm.internal.network.OkHttpAuthenticationServer.loginUser(OkHttpAuthenticationServer.java:53) at io.realm.SyncUser.login(SyncUser.java:189) at io.realm.SyncUser$1.run(SyncUser.java:228) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 06-06 10:43:06.331 12633-12771/io.realm.realmtasks I/REALM_JAVA: Failed authenticating user. UNKNOWN(-1) java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.9 (port 9080) after 10000ms at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:169) at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:886) at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.java:61) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:187) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.buildConnection(RealConnection.java:173) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:114) at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:193) at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:129) at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:98) at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:109) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:124) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:170) at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:60) at io.realm.internal.network.OkHttpAuthenticationServer.authenticate(OkHttpAuthenticationServer.java:111) at io.realm.internal.network.OkHttpAuthenticationServer.loginUser(OkHttpAuthenticationServer.java:53) at io.realm.SyncUser.login(SyncUser.java:189) at io.realm.SyncUser$1.run(SyncUser.java:228) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)`

can someone please help me out, I want to follow the realm/doc tutorials so i can learn and implement realm in future projects but I cant figure out why my connection is timing out. Thank you guys

Comment: Is your phone on the same network/LAN with wifi?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes I added my phone to my LAN and it worked like a charm, appreciate you.